Unable to connect SSH repository: existing repository spec is different; use upsert flag to force update; difference in keys
We are trying to connect argocd with SSH RSA 256 key, but getting below error

Unable to connect SSH repository: existing repository spec is different; use upsert flag to force update; difference in keys "SSHPrivateKey,InsecureIgnoreHostKey,Name,Project"


We use Azure DevOps.
We are using Argo CD v2.5.10 and EKS v1.25.
